# what is best to use canvas or img for frequent updates?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript timer.

It refreshes the img src on a 200ms interval.

I have taken a look at the canvas object.  I am unsure whether it is recommended to use the canvas instead of the img element?

I am running tests on both and cannot see any differences in performance.

This is my code for using the timer/img:

This is my code:

```
var timer4x4
var cache4x4 = new Image();
var alias = 'test';
var lastUpdate = 0;



function setImageSrc4x4(src) {
    live4x4.src = src;
    timer4x4 = window.setTimeout(swapImages4x4, 200);
}

function swapImages4x4() {
    cache4x4.onload = function () {
        setImageSrc4x4(cache4x4.src);
    };

    cache4x4.onerror = function () {
        setImageSrc4x4("http://127.0.0.1/images/ERROR.jpg");
    };
    cache4x4.src = null;
    cache4x4.src = 'http://127.0.0.1/Cloud/LiveXP.ashx?id=' + createGuid() + '&Alias=' + alias + '&ReSync=' + reSync;
    reSync = 0;
}
```

*nb will add canvas code in a bit

I am streaming images from my client desktop PC to my web server. I am trying to display as many images (FPS) as possible.  The image is a container for 4 smaller images. Stitched up on the client and sent to the server.

I have Googled and it says if doing pixel manipulation and aniumation use canvas.

But, I am just doing animation.

Thanks

Comment: @close Hi, why the recommendation to close? I can/will amend my question to make it more acceptable? pls?

Comment: I agree, people should provide commentary on downvotes and close-flags in order to nurture improvements for the entire community. Anyway, your question could greatly benefit from more details. People can more easily evaluate which method is best for you if you provide some more detail on how and where you want to use img/canvas and why.

Comment: could it be more faster if you add multiple image elements and hide/show wanted element instead of changing src? Just thinking..

Comment: @Hardy Hi, thanks for your thoughts.Are you suggesting having say 10 img objects (9 are hidden and 1 is visible). updating the hidden imgs 1 at a time and 2). toggle which img to show the user? I had thought of that but I was worried that the management of this 'Live Stream' would become unmanageable..

Comment: Yes, like that.. would be interesting if someone would benchmark that.. of course all image elements should be added first on init.

Comment: Yes, would be interesting to do this. I am about to do some work on the client before I attempt this though. Will report back when done, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canvas` element was designed to draw / edit / interact with images in it. If all you do is display the image, then you don't need that and a simple `img` is the semantically correct choice (with the added bonus of being compatible on more devices).

In both cases, the performance will be similar (if not the same) because the only thing to happen is that the image is downloaded.

Comment: yours and @squareCat are similar in answers.  The relying on HTML5 is a concern. I was prepared to restrict what spec the app would run on but if there is no performance gain then there is no need. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

While performance-wise you won't notice much of a difference, since you still cannot fully rely on HTML5 support yet, it is probably best to go with the `img`-solution for now.